# Weird output while placing elasticsearch curl command in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, curl, elasticsearch

I have elasticsearch curl command which I have placed in one shell script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash


totalCount=`curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_all/_count?pretty=true' -d '{
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
                "must" : [
                        {
                        "match" : {
                                "type" : "mtaLogs"
                        }} ,
                        {
                        "filtered" : {
                        "filter" : {
                                "range" : {
                                        "@timestamp" : {
                                                "from" : "2015-07-27T00:00:01",
                                                "to" : "2015-07-27T23:59:59"
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                        }
                        }
                ]
        }
    }
}' | jq '.count'`

echo "Total mtaLogs count is $totalCount"
```

Now it is supposed to show output only as `Total mtaLogs count is <some count>`

But it is showing output as

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0    98    0    98    0   755   7572  58337 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
Total mtaLogs count is 39
```

Why am I getting this unnecessary table output on console?

Any help here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to add the `-s` or `-silent` switch to the curl command and it will be executed silently without the verbose table, i.e.

```
totalCount=`curl -s -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_all/_count?pretty=true' -d '{
                  ^
                  |
                  |
                 HERE
```

Comment: Thanks.. it helped... :)